# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Before posting this question, I tried majority of possible solutions that were offered in other SO discussions, but none of them worked. Could it be something else that I am missing? 
I am using NetBeans 8.2 and whenever I run project it shows this error:

> COMPILATION ERROR :
>
> Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
>      javac: invalid target release: 9
>      Usage: javac  
>      use -help for a list of possible options
>
> 1 error
>
> BUILD FAILURE
>
> Total time: 1.124s
>      Finished at: Wed May 10 21:39:09 EEST 2017
>      Final Memory: 6M/92M
>
> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler  plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project javacv-example: Compilation failure
>
> Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
>
> javac: invalid target release: 9
>
> Usage: javac

pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.imesha.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.22</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
            <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.8</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: You need to use JDK 9 for target/source having Java 9 ...and for such things you need to use a newer version of maven-compiler-plugin (3.6.1)...